# Change spinner color on a toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-styles

I'm working on a sample Android app with a toolbar with a spinner "filter news" that I want to use a filter of items.

[image]

I need to:

- change colour of the spinner text on the toolbar (Figure 2)
  [image]
- change background colour of item list (Figure 3)
  [image]

Full code is available on GitHub, [here](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton-examples/tree/master/rss-reader). Some xml code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
  [...]
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/love_music"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="@string/backdrop_title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="@string/backdrop_subtitle"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_subtitle" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
[...]
```

**spinner_dropdown_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    ></TextView>
```

And styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution: I was using an old layout style for spinner and its item. Changing in MainActivity spinner declaration in:

```
...
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                R.array.article_filter_text, R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
...
```

And having spinner_dropdown_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    ></TextView>
```

I got:

[image]

And:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom java class extending **ArrayAdapter** and apply the logic there to change your text color.

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context mContext;
private List<String> mStringList;

public SpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<String> spinnerItems) {
    super(context, resource, spinnerItems);
    mContext = context;
    mStringList = spinnerItems;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return spinnerView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return spinnerView(position, convertView, parent);
}

private View spinnerView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        // Your spinner dropdown item xml here
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext). inflate(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //Custom logic here, example below
    String matchDay = mStringList.get(position);
    holder.mMatchday = convertView.findViewById(R.id.matchday);
    holder.mDates = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_dates);
    holder.mMatchday.setText(matchDay);


    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {

    private TextView mMatchday, mDates;

}
```

**In Ur Activity**

```
List<String> stringList= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        stringList.add("String " + (i + 1));
    }

SpinnerAdapter dataAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.format_home_spinner, stringList);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer, but I want to resolve it without defining a spinner adapter.